# How do I get the requestor's IP address inside a container in a google cloud k8 cluster?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, gcloud

When I try printing out the `x-forwarded-for` value I get the ip address of a Node inside the cluster instead of the requesting client.

I believe my current setup looks something like this:

External LB -> ingress -> nginx -> container

If I directly access nginx, I get the correct ip address. My ingress is configured with `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-forwarded-headers: "true"`

Comment: Hi Jason M have you got time to go through my last response, kindly revert back if you still have some queries.

Answer (score 0):

There is a workaround available for this as mentioned in this [Official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/best-practices/networking#use-local-traffic-policy), [using an internal network passthrough load balancer](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/internal-load-balancing) and configuring the `externalTrafficPolicy` as `local` you can resolve this issue. However it is not suggested to use `externalTrafficPolicy: local` sometimes because it will cause less optimal load balancing.

Also try the below mentioned troubleshooting steps which will be useful for resolving this issue:

- Check the type of load balancer you are using as mentioned in this [document](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/features#ip_addresses), only application load balancers support `x-forwarded-for` protocol the remaining load balancers support a different protocol.
- If you are using the application load balancer check whether all your NGINX configurations are correct.

Try to provide your NGINX and Kubernetes manifests or steps for replicating this issue so that it will be useful for providing a detailed solution.

Comment: Meanwhile as you are able to get the client IP from your nginx, you can also try creating a configmap and store the client IP address in the environment variables and expose them to your application.

Comment: Thank you! I'm using passthrough network load balancer, which according to the link should preserve the source ip? When I check the ingress controller logs, though, requests coming in have an IP of a node within the cluster.

I can get the client ip from nginx only when I connect to it directly 
through a tunnel, bypassing ingress and the network lb

Comment: @JasonM Yes, **`passthrough load balancers`** preserve **client IP** or **source IP**, however you need to set **`externalTrafficPolicy: local`** as the load balancers will follow the **proxy protocol** which will alter the **client IP** or **source IP**. If you are using an **application load balancer** then you can use **`X-forwarded-for`** to get the **client IP directly**.

Comment: @JasonM have you gone through my response..? please revert back if you are facing some issues..

Comment: I haven't proceeded with this yet since you mentioned that it leads to less optimal load balancing. What I don't understand is if the ip address is preserved why isn't there a more straightforward way to access it.

Comment: @JasonM as mention in this [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/features#ip_addresses) each load balancer uses different type of protocol for preserving the client IP, and passthrough load balancer uses proxy protocol for preserving the client IP. Since passthrough load balancer is using the proxy  protocol the client IP will be replaced once it crosses the ingress hence you need to use `externalTrafficPolicy: local`